A SEDE query that worked for years is now timing out for the last ten attempts
The SEDE query All my posts on the SE network (with Markdown and HTML content plus editors and status) has been working for years, however over the last week, and the last ten attempts, this error appears:

Line 0: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I'm using the same account as always, 4775729. (My own)
Proposed duplicate
Another question from 2017 was proposed to be a duplicate:

"Execution Timeout Expired" for some popular queries on data.stackexchange.com

That question however doesn't refer to a specific query. The query in this question can actually be looked at and a solution proposed. For example, someone might propose adding a line (or two) of code that uses an index.
Problem solved December 22, 2024
Stack Exchange Data Explorer may have been modified. In any case, after failing for many months, the query now works again. Proof is this question is now visible on my website:


"Any ideas how to fix?": Yes, stop abusing SEDE as a programmatic data source (context from your prior question). You are using SEDE for a purpose for which it was not designed. Use the SE API for this data access, as the SE API is specifically designed for bulk/programmatic access to data such as you are doing.

@Makyen maybe SE shouldn't have killed the data dump then.

@Makyen That query and derivatives of it has been run ~10,000 times by other people IIRC. I'm only responsible for running it 52 times a year for 3 years. The spirit of a SEDE Query is it is open source that a large number of people benefit from. Correct me if I'm wrong but SE API queries are not open source?

@Makyen I strongly disagree. The API requires much more advanced skills and/or spending much more time. SEDE is the easy way, and it exists for exactly such things. Please don't discourage people from using it.

@ShadowWizard Then we are going to disagree. SEDE is not intended for programmatic access, which is what the OP is using it for, as described in their other question. Programmatic access to SE data is intended to be through the SE API. Your statement that it's more advanced skills is inaccurate. It is, however, a different skillset, but it's a skillset that the OP, by their statements in their other question, has demonstrated that that do have, as they are explicitly interfacing the query with Python.

@Makyen I agree that it can be considered abuse to e.g. query SEDE with a script every few seconds, and such things can and should be blocked by SE. But that's not the case here. As long as the "programmatic access" is limited and well timed, I really can't see any problem with it, it's just automating something that one would have done anyway, manually.

Instead of going over all databases, only visit the ones that you actually have an account on: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1868608

@rene Yes I've been thinking about that this morning. Frank (below) keeps mentioning how SO has a huge database. I do have some good answers there but I guess I can port them to Ask Ubuntu and skip Stack Overflow.Alternatively there might be a "member of community" flag that can be checked to skip the sites programmatically in the query? Unfortunately I've just learned enough SQL to write a music player in python which isn't all that complicated. Hopefully in a week I'll get the Convert Stack Exchange to Website application running again. Thanks for the tip Rene!

@rene It appears SEDE fixed a bug or increased running time. See my question revision with problem solved. Nonetheless thank you for your suggestion!


Any ideas how to fix?

Yes, I believe we should increase the max SEDE query running time. Many SEDE queries don't work anymore because the SE data size (mostly SO) increases while the max SEDE query running time doesn't increase (other factors are indexes and server hardware).

But it's never timed out in three years. Did SEDE suddenly slow down recently making the query timeout?

@WinEunuuchs2Unix what was the SEDE query running time, before it started to time out? Was it close to the max SEDE query running time?

I honestly don't know. I did get the feeling a few months ago it was running slower a minute or two? Originally (three years ago) I think it was a lot faster perhaps 30 seconds? Sorry I never kept track of the time. The query scrapes Q&A posts which is around 4K posts that really hasn't changed much the last couple of years.

I just timed it with computer's minute clock and the SEDE Query times out after 2 minutes and presents the error message.

@WinEunuuchs2Unix sounds like he SEDE query running time progressively increases then one day hits the max time. Happened to me too on a few queries.

Sounds like either SEDE Query interpreter is getting code bloat or more users are signed on and running queries. Because it's Sunday night here I think it's the former and not the latter.

@WinEunuuchs2UnixI think just because the SE data size (mostly SO) increases

Oh I assumed SE Data Explorer would have my account number indexed and just do 4,000 reads. I didn't think it would read millions of posts to see which ones were for my account number.

@WinEunuuchs2Unix "I did get the feeling a few months ago it was running slower a minute or two? Originally (three years ago) I think it was a lot faster perhaps 30 second" sounds like the SE data size (mostly SO) increase caused a slower running time. But let's see what others say, I'm no expert in SEDE.

Unfortunately the question got closed. However the duplicate doesn't refer to a specific query that can be reviewed for changes. I'm thinking my query needs an index, or should limit itself to sites I've actually posted on and not all SE sites.

It's unlikely that the query timeout would be significantly increased...for reason too long for a comment. I think you'll be much more likely to entice the company into including additional indexes that are useful to improving performance.

@AMtwo thanks, if too long for a comment, you're very welcome to post an answer on https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/400844/178179 :)

@FranckDernoncourt I upvoted rene's answer. Tune your query.

Accepting your answer because question is closed and no other answers can be posted. I still haven't rewritten the query using Rene's suggestion (comment under question), but hopefully on the weekend I'll find time.

It appears SEDE fixed a bug or increased running time like you suggested. See my question revision with problem solved.

@WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks, looks faster indeed! idk if new index, new server or fixed bug.

I think they fixed a bug introduced in an update in the fall. At that point they should have un-closed the question and posted an answer detailing the bug fix. Regardless, it is a nice Christmas present to have my website working again! Thanks again for your valued attention.
